# 301 redirects is not working with long query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a long url with query string which i want to redirect permanently to a new URL but its not working.

I am writing following to the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /view-all/?c=low-loader-transport&c_new_value=false&sc=&sc_new_value=false&State_Suburb=on&lsu=&lsu_new_value=false&lst=&lst_new_value=false&l_ht[]=607&l_ht[_new_value]=false&l_t=578&search-now.x=80&search-now.y=21 http://www.testdomain.com/low-loader-transport
```

Am i doing something wrong?

There is one more 301 redirect in my htaccess file which is working fine. see following URL which works fine :

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.testdomain.com
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=low-loader-transport&c_new_value=false&sc=&sc_new_value=false&State_Suburb=on&lsu=&lsu_new_value=false&lst=&lst_new_value=false&l_ht[]=607&l_ht[_new_value]=false&l_t=578&search-now.x=80&search-now\.y=21$
RewriteRule ^view-all/?$ http://www.testdomain.com/low-loader-transport/? [L,R=301]
```